# Add numbers in array while avoiding nil elements

Tags: ruby

I want to add the numbers in the array and ignore the nil elements. My solution obviously doesn't work.

```
array = [3,4,5,6,nil,9,nil,9,3]

def add(array)
  array.inject(0){|memo,s|s.is_a?Integer ? memo+=s : next}
end
```

Comment: Just return `memo` in the last part of the ternary instead of using `next`. Also, with inject, the `memo += s` is identical to `memo + s`, so the equal sign is really redundant here.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why your version doesn't work is simple: the return value of the block becomes the `memo` value for the next iteration. In the case that `s` is not an `Integer`, you simply return nothing, i.e. `nil`, so during the next iteration, `memo` is `nil`.

You can fix it by simply returning memo unchanged:

```
def add(array)
  array.inject(0) { |memo, s| s.is_a? Integer ? memo += s : next memo }
  #                                                              ↑↑↑↑
end
```

This is the smallest possible change that will fix your problem.

A block normally returns the value of the last expression evaluated inside the block, so the `next` is actually not necessary:

```
def add(array)
  array.inject(0) { |memo, s| s.is_a? Integer ? memo += s : memo }
end
```

It doesn't make sense to assign to `memo`, it goes out of scope at the end of the block anyway, and you never use it again:

```
def add(array)
  array.inject(0) { |memo, s| s.is_a? Integer ? memo + s : memo }
end
```

According to the standard community style guides, argument lists to message sends should be enclosed in parenthesis, unless it's a "procedure-like" message send (e.g. `puts`, `require`) or a "keyword-like" one (e.g. `attr_accessor`):

```
def add(array)
  array.inject(0) { |memo, s| s.is_a?(Integer) ? memo + s : memo }
end
```

Personally, I don't like the conditional operator. That's a stylistic issue, though, but I much prefer this:

```
def add(array)
  array.inject(0) { |memo, s| if s.is_a?(Integer) then memo + s else memo end }
end
```

However, a much easier solution is to remove the `nil` elements before you iterate:

```
def add(array)
  array.reject {|s| s.nil? }.inject(0) { |memo, s| memo + s }
end
```

Which can be more elegantly written using [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc)

```
def add(array)
  array.reject(&:nil?).inject(0) { |memo, s| memo + s }
end
```

But is actually just equivalent to the more readable:

```
def add(array)
  array.compact.inject(0) { |memo, s| memo + s }
end
```

[`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) allows you to pass the name of the combining method as a [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html):

```
def add(array)
  array.compact.inject(0, :+)
end
```

And that is just the same as [`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sum):

```
def add(array)
  array.compact.sum
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `compact`

```
array.compact.reduce(0,:+)
```

Comment: Use `reduce(0, :+)` otherwise if the array has zero non-nil elements this returns `nil`, not `0`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that edge case. I was assuming the array had nil elements

Comment: `(array-[nil]).inject(:+)` just for fun ))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways:

```
array = [3,4,5,6,nil,9,nil,9,3]
array.sum(&:to_i) # => 39
array.reject(&:nil?).sum # => 39
```

You can use `compact` instead of `reject(&:nil?)`:

```
array.compact.sum # => 39
```

If you don't have `sum` available, which you should if you're using a reasonably recent Ruby, you can use `inject(:+)`:

```
array.compact.inject(:+) # => 39
```

---

```
require 'fruity'

compare do
  sum_to_i { array.sum(&:to_i) }
  reject_nil { array.reject(&:nil?).sum }
  compact_reduce { array.compact.reduce(0,:+) }
  compact_sum { array.compact.sum }
  compact_inject { array.compact.inject(:+) }
  do_not_do_this { array.reject{|a| a.nil?}.inject(0){|memo,a| memo+=a} }
end

# >> Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> compact_sum is faster than compact_inject by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> compact_inject is similar to compact_reduce
# >> compact_reduce is faster than sum_to_i by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> sum_to_i is faster than reject_nil by 1.9x ± 0.1
# >> reject_nil is faster than do_not_do_this by 2.0x ± 0.1
```

[Jörg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093625/128421) is clearly the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
array.reject{|a| a.nil?}.inject(0){|memo,a| memo+=a}
```

Comment: While it'll work it's slower, and will continue to get slower as the array size grows. You're better off using the built-in methods as demonstrated by http://stackoverflow.com/a/42093625/128421. Also, unless you intend to select your answer it's better to not add your "final" code as an answer.